# The image of $\mathbb{N}$ under the predecessor function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given the predecessor function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ as $\{(a+1,a) \ | \ a\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and I am asked what the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under the said function is, where $\mathbb{N}:= \{0,1,2,...\}$.

The solution I am given is $\{n-1 \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{-1\}\cup \mathbb{N}$. The $\{-1\}$ is where I don't understand; presumably this is the image corresponding to an input of $0$. To my knowledge, an image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $f$ just means the set of elements which has a relation from a restricted domain $\mathbb{N}$ (restricted in the sense that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$).

By this logic, starting with $0$, if I let $a=0$ and input it to $f$, shouldn't $f(0)$ be $(0+1=1,0)=(1,0)$, i.e. the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $f$, with input$=0$, is $0$ (because it's just $a$, which we assumed to be $0$)? Why is it $-1$ instead?

Comment: The image must be clearly $\mathbb N \cup \{ -1 \}$ because **in** $\mathbb Z$, the predecessor of $0$ is $-1$, the predecessor of $1$ is $0$, of $2$ is $1$, and so on. Thus, we have the "equation" : $predecessor (n)=n-1$, i.e. the"couples" forming the function are : $(n,n-1)$, i.e. $(n+1,n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of $f$ are the ordered pairs $\langle a+1,a\rangle$ for $a\in\Bbb Z$. In each such pair the input to $f$ is the $a+1$, and the output from $f$ is the $a$. Thus, to find out what $f(0)$ is, you must find a pair $\langle a+1,a\rangle\in f$ such that $a+1=0$; clearly that means that $a=-1$ and hence that the pair is $\langle 0,-1\rangle$, meaning that $f(0)=-1$.

And of course this fits perfectly with what we mean when we talk about the predecessor of an integer: the predecessor of $0$ is the integer immediately preceding $0$ in the usual ordering of the integers, and that integer is $-1$.

Comment: Thank you! Is that because the input of a function is always the first term of the ordered pair, and in this case a+1 is the first term, not a?
I was confused because I thought a is supposed to be the input.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, it's the first member of the ordered pair that comes from the domain, so it's always the input. You're welcome!